# Distance and spacing of LED growlights for propagation

Tags: indoors, seedlings, propagation, grow-lamp, led

I am planning to make an indoor propagation setup which consists of 
h:30cm x w:40 x L:50cm recycled polystyrene boxes and full spectrum LED panels. Clearly, the biggest limitation is height in this case. I might join two boxes to double the height, if necessary.  The LED panels I have seen keep a temperature of 25C while in operation, but I will clearly drill some holes for ventilation.

The setup is intended to start seeds and grow them vegetatively until they can be hardened off and planted out (this will include vegetable plants).

**Edit:** I am planning on leaving the polystyrene lid on and attaching the LED panel to it, with the wiring at the top or side; but I am open to other solutions if strictly necessary. The boxes would be placed in a cold part of the house, where the temperature range is 13-18C.

My questions are:

1) What should be the distance for, say, 25W, 45W, 75W panels like [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TOPLANET-Update-Reflector-Spectrum-Greenhouse/dp/B078R9DG21/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1549562446&sr=8-5&keywords=full%20spectrum%20led%20panel)?

2) Would spacing be a problem in the case of a panel? Should I buy strips instead and evenly space them out?

3) How many hours of light per day are suggested in the case of seedlings?

[image] [image]

Comment: Are you planning on leaving the polystyrene covers on the containers with the lights inside? Taking the covers off and putting the lights just above the containers' rims? I assume that the containers will be indoors - do you have an idea of the ambient temperature where they'll be kept?

Comment: I have added to the question above.

Comment: I looked at the lights from your link and they recommend a minimum of 120 cm from seedlings. That's not going to happen in a 30 cm tall cooler.

Comment: The problem is that I have seen many inconsistent indications on similar panels. Without a lumen specification nor any knowledge (on my part) of what criteria to apply, I don't see how I should decide what to use...

Comment: Having started seeds under lights I found they will get too tall/leggy at 25 C. I suggest a soil temperature of 15 to 20 C to get compact /bushy growth of commercial plants. Although actual sprouting is better at 25 C ( depending on the specific plant) So I sprouted separately from the growing conditions.

Comment: I envision mold problems if you leave the lids on those containers.